# I want to print text slowly and also have it as a input, however at the end it says None

Tags: python

I have defined this function to print text slowly:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

def print_slow(s):
    for letter in s:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.075)

s_name = str(input(print_slow("\n\nWhat is your name?   (EASTER EGG CODE: \"blackbeard\")\n>>")))
```

The slow text works, however at the end of the input it outputs:

```
What is your name?   (EASTER EGG CODE: "blackbeard")
>>None
```

How do I get rid of the `None`?

Comment: Minor code improvement suggestion: In python3 `print` is a function. Which allows to simplify your function to `print(letter, flush=True)` + the pause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`print_slow()` returns `None` which you pass to the `input()` function. That function uses that argument as the *prompt* to show the user when asking for input:

```
>>> input(None)
None
```

`None` is the default return value of any function, unless you give it an explicit return value with a `return` statement, which your function lacks.

Call `input()` *separately*, you don't *have* to give it a prompt to print:

```
print_slow("\n\nWhat is your name?   (EASTER EGG CODE: \"blackbeard\")\n>>")
s_name = input()
```

The `str()` call is redundant, in Python 3, `input()` returns a string, always.

Comment: To solve this, add `return ""` to the end of `print_slow`. Then the prompt will be the empty string.

Comment: @kindall: or, just not pass the result to `input()` in the first place.